# OpenCV найти символы на изображении

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, машинное-обучение, opencv

Вот код которым пользуюсь,для некоторых тестовых изображений он работает,но если я беру то изображение которое в последующем хочу распознать то ничего не получается [image: введите сюда описание изображения]   Так же посоветуйте как мне лучше обработать изображение для последующего распознавания.

```
def letters_extract(image_file: str, out_size=28):
img = cv2.imread(image_file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_erode = cv2.erode(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=1)
# Get contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_erode, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
output = img.copy()
letters = []
for idx, contour in enumerate(contours):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if hierarchy[0][idx][3] == 0:
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (70, 0, 0), 1)
        letter_crop = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]           
        # Resize letter canvas to square
        size_max = max(w, h)
        letter_square = 255 * np.ones(shape=[size_max, size_max], dtype=np.uint8)
        if w > h:
            # Enlarge image top-bottom           
            y_pos = size_max // 2 - h // 2
            letter_square[y_pos:y_pos + h, 0:w] = letter_crop
        elif w < h:
            # Enlarge image left-right    
            x_pos = size_max // 2 - w // 2
            letter_square[0:h, x_pos:x_pos + w] = letter_crop
        else:
            letter_square = letter_crop

        # Resize letter to 28x28 and add letter and its X-coordinate
        letters.append((x, w, cv2.resize(letter_square, (out_size, out_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)))

# Sort array in place by X-coordinate
letters.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
#Save letters
counter = 1
for i in range(len(letters)):
    for j in range(len(letters[i])):
        cv2.imshow("0", letters[i][j])
   # cv2.waitKey(0)
   # cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("imag/"+str(counter)+".jpg", letters[i][j])
    counter = counter + 1

return letters

def img_to_str(model: Any, image_file: str):
letters = letters_extract(image_file)
s_out = ""
for i in range(len(letters)):
    dn = letters[i + 1][0] - letters[i][0] - letters[i][1] if i < len(letters) - 1 else 0
    s_out += emnist_predict_img(model, letters[i][2])
    if (dn > letters[i][1] / 4):
        s_out += ' '
return s_out
```

Comment: @alexis031182 извиняюсь,может быть Вы поможете? В вопросе с поискам жесткого диска у Вас получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот кот работает лучше,но я не могу понять как мне его ограничить в плане получения контуров.

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\dennn\\PycharmProjects\\untitled2\\imag\\output5.jpg')

 # grayscale
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.waitKey(0)

 # binarize
 ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
 cv2.waitKey(0)

 # find contours
 ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

 # sort contours
 sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

 for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
     # Get bounding box
     x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

     # Getting ROI
     roi = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

     # show ROI
     # cv2.imwrite('roi_imgs.png', roi)
     cv2.imshow('charachter' + str(i), roi)
     cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)
     cv2.waitKey(0)

 cv2.imshow('marked areas', img)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```